# How to remove all javascript from the page load except what is embedded in the html pupeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Well guys, I have this script that adds the product to the cart, but I need it to work as quickly as possible, currently it’s working for about 19 seconds if you run this code, of course there are a number of factors that should be taken into account  consideration, one of them is the response time of the website and everything ... Well, I took almost all the resources on this site to load faster

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType

But I did not remove the script loading (javascript), but I want to remove all the javascript from the page except what is embedded in the html, that is, I want to prevent all references to javascript files except the javascript that is inserted in the html, and I would like  to know if it is possible to disable html text loading, this is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');       
const fs = require('fs').promises;                                                                                                              
(async () => {                                                                    
 try{                                              
  console.log("Started!")                        
  const browser = await 
  puppeteer.launch({         
   executablePath:'/usr/bin/chromium',            
   headlesss:false,                                
  });
 const page = await browser.newPage();      
 await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });                                          
 await page.setRequestInterception(true);        
 const blockedResourceTypes = ["image", "bacon", "imageset", "font", "stylesheet", "main_frame", "sub_frame", "object", "texttrack", "csp_report"]
 const allowedRequest = req => !blockedResourceTypes.includes(req.resourceType())                       
 page.on('request', (req) => {                    
  if (allowedRequest(req)) {                       
   req.continue();                                
 }                                               
  else {                                           
   req.abort();                                   
  }                                             
 });                                             
 const cookiesString = await 
 fs.readFile('./cookies.json');                                      
 const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
 await page.setCookie(...cookies);               
 await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-phantom-gt-elite-3d-unissex-153-169-171-316414?gridPosition=A1', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout:0});
 await page.waitForXPath('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]', { visible:true, timeout:0});      
 const tamanho = await page.$x('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]')                            
 await tamanho[0].click('//label[@for="tamanho__idM40F395"]');                                   
 await page.waitForSelector('button#btn-comprar')                                                
 await page.click('button#btn-comprar')
 console.log("Add to car!")         
}
catch{                                           
 console.log("Error, element not found or unexpected error")}               
})();
```

How can I remove all javascript except the javascript embedded in html?

Comment: I've seen a few questions now on this from you and I get the sense there's some underlying problem you're trying to solve. Are you sure this isn't an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)? Wouldn't pretty much all of the scripts that the page loads be embedded in the HTML? This seems like a pretty arbitrary decision to block dynamically-injected JS but not statically-present script -- can you explain why you're making this decision and what purpose this is supposed to fulfill for your application? Thanks.

Comment: My script is all ready, the only thing I want to finally finish is to make sure that only the javascript embedded in the html is executed and if possible remove the load of some html tags, my script is already working the problem is that it runs on  18 or 19 seconds and I want to make it faster, that's why

Comment: The script is ready, I just want to improve

Comment: Sounds good, I was thinking something was timing out or otherwise broken. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to block all files with the extension .js after taking a deep look at Google, I used this code:

```
req.url().endsWith('.js')
```

And then after that I use if to make the condition structure and tell my code if it should load or abort, with `req.continue` or `req.abort`